# How to block access from outside to .php files in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, security

on my wordpress website i have some critical .php files which include code like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_server, $db_benutzer, $db_passwort, $db_name);
```

Obviously i dont want anyone but me to have access to those files, otherwise they could connect to my database. Howerver i have to run them from other scripts.

I know that you cannot see the code of the functions.php, how can i do the same with my files?

They are stored in the folder:
mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/js

Comment: place outside of webroot

Comment: you can limit access to these files configuring your web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop .php files from being run from outside of your WP environment by checking for one of the WP constants:

`if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;`

Hope that helps